# #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1241

In the following query am trying to get one image per category

```
SELECT  l.*
FROM    (
   SELECT  id AS category_id,
           COALESCE(
           (
           SELECT  *
           FROM    images li
           WHERE li.category_id = dlo.id

           ORDER BY
                       li.save_status DESC, li.category_id DESC, li.id DESC
           LIMIT 1
           ), 0) AS mid
   FROM    cats_imgs dlo where id='1'
   ) lo
JOIN    images l
ON      l.save_status = '3'
   AND l.category_id >= lo.category_id
   AND l.category_id <= lo.category_id
   AND l.id >= lo.mid
```

but keep getting the following error :

```
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: replace `*` with a single column for `images li`

Comment: Wow , worked :) post it as an answer plz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

replace `*` with a single column for `images li`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  Your 3rd level select statement (`SELECT  * FROM    images li`) needs to return a single value, since the 2nd level select statement (`SELECT  id AS category_id,COALESCE( ...`) is expecting only one value in its place holder.

For my case, it worked.  Here I also averaged the data from a second based table (`SecondBasis`) to the values in the one minute basis table (`MinuteBasis`):

```
SELECT MinuteBasis.time, MinuteBasis.avg_t, MinuteBasis.avg_p,MinuteBasis.avg_t2,
  (SELECT avg(SecondBasis.m1)
   FROM SecondBasis
   WHERE SecondBasis.time BETWEEN MinuteBasis.time AND addtime (MinuteBasis.time,'0 0:00:59'))
  (SELECT avg(SecondBasis.m2)
   FROM SecondBasis
   WHERE SecondBasis.time BETWEEN MinuteBasis.time AND addtime (MinutBasis.time,'0 0:00:59'))
FROM MinuteBasis
WHERE MinuteBasis.time BETWEEN '2012-05-02 8:30:00' AND '2012-05-02 8:44:59' ;
```